# Reload data in Asynchronous Loading

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, swift3, uiimageview

I have implemented asynchronous image loading into my swift project to load in a series of images in cells in a table.

I have done so with the following extension

```
extension UIImageView {
public func imageFromServerURL(urlString: String, defaultImage : String?) {
    if let di = defaultImage {
        self.image = UIImage(named: di)
    }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: NSURL(string: urlString)! as URL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print(error ?? "error")
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
            let image = UIImage(data: data!)
            self.image = image

        })

    }).resume()
  }
}
```

I call the method by declaring an instance method

```
let imageView = UIImageView()
```

and then running this in my code later.

```
cell.posterImageView!.image = UIImage(imageView.imageFromServerURL(urlString: posterImageURL as! String ,defaultImage: "noPosterImage.png" ))
```

This works mostly except the images don't update in my table until I scroll the image out of view and then scroll it back into view.

After doing my own research I found  this method that seems like it could help me

```
self.tableview.reloadData()
```

When i tried to implement it into my code like this inside of my extension

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
        let image = UIImage(data: data!)
        self.image = image
        self.tableview.reloadData()
    })
```

I recieve the error

> Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'tableview'

I'm new to swift so i'm not quite sure how to fix this error, I'm sure it's something stupidly easy

Any advice on how to either fix this error or simply fix the problem overall?

Comment: **Try this one it's Working Code** https://stackoverflow.com/a/51746517/10150796

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually use IBOutlets to connect the views from the storyboard to your UIViewController. In your case you would connect the tableView from the storyboard to the viewController which owns the UIViewController-instance in the starboard.

Then you can call `tableView.reload()` inside viewController to reload the table.

It is not possible to connect from storyboard to an imageView so you can't connect the tableView to your custom UIImageView class.

Reading on [IBOutlets](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/xcode/what-is-an-iboutlet), [Storyboards](https://www.raywenderlich.com/160521/storyboards-tutorial-ios-11-part-1) for you to work through.

Comment: Could you provide an example for clarification (if this isn't asking too much)

Comment: @Vapidant For connecting IBOutlets or for reloading the table? tableView.reload() reloads all the images there are, by calling on its `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` and in your `UITableViewDelegate` then you can load the image again after which you return the view. The alternative would be to store references to the imageViews while configuring each cell and when you want to reload images you iterate over each and set the new image.